# Listview execution failed

Tags: c#, listview

I do not know what happens, when I execute the button event (StartClickingButton_Click), the click coordinates stored in the ListView are executed one after the other, and not only the one that I select is executed (when selecting fields of the textbox are filled ).

This is the code that I am using.

-The problem is that when executing the button event, I go through all the coordinates stored in the ListView, and not the one I have selected.

Thanks for your comments and possible solutions.

```
private void StartClickingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int iterations = 1;
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        List<int> times = new List<int>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in PositionsListView.Items)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(item.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
            times.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[2].Text));

            points.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        try
        {
            ClickThreadHelper helper = new ClickThreadHelper() { Points = points, Iterations = iterations, Times = times };
            ClickThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(helper.Run));
            ClickThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So do you get an error? am still not sure what's the issue here?

Comment: The problem is that when executing the button event, I go through all the coordinates stored in the ListView, and not the one I have selected.

Comment: You are looping thru all the items of the list view in foreach loop. How do you know that the selected item is not being accessed in the loop?

Comment: because when selecting it, it does not effect the event on the selected item, but on all of the list.